# how can i close modal after form submitting gives an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, redux-form, antd

this is my modal component,

it closes after submit success, but stays on the page if submit fails

I use the redux form and ant design

```
Modal.confirm({
  title: title
  content:delete
  okText: yes
  cancelText: no
  okType: 'danger',
  onOk: () => {
      this.props.delete(this.props.id);
  },
});
```

Comment: https://www.antdv.com/components/modal/#Confirmation-modal-dialog shows an example at the bottom using destroy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below:

```
Modal.confirm({
  title: title
  content:delete
  okText: yes
  cancelText: no
  okType: 'danger',
  onOk: () => {
      this.props.delete(this.props.id);
  },
  onCancel() {
  console.log('Cancel'); -------> Your desired Event 
 },
});
```

Comment: i pass a setTimeout